# what happen here color and border not work

Tags: html, css, python-3.x

my CSS are not working there is no error but it does not work I tried to fail  lot's of time but couldn't find anything wrong, please help me find this problem>>my CSS are not working there is no error but it does not work I tried to fail  lot's of time but couldn't find anything wrong, please help me find this problem >>my CSS is working there is no error but it does not work I tried to fail  lot's of time but couldn't find anything wrong, please help me find this problem*

**Here is HTML5**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load static %}
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Django Level Two</title>
      {# Main Css #}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/mystyle.css" %}" />
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>Hi Welcome two Django Level Two</h1>
      <h2>Here are your access records:</h2>

      <div class="djangotwo">
        {% if access_records %}
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th>Site Name</th>
            <th>Date Accessed</th>
          </thead>
          {% for acc in access_records %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ acc.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ acc.date }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </table>

        {% else %}
        <p>NO ACCESS RECORDS FOUNDS!</p>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

**Here is CSS**

```css
h1{
  color: red;
}

.djangotwo{
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: what is `{# Main Css #}`?

Answer (score 0):

Try just changing this line from :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/mystyle.css" %}" />
```

to :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css":w/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try double checking the file URL, maybe you made a typo in the directory.

The documentation for Django might be a bit old, but I still recommend checking it out, since there might be something you forgot: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial06/

from the documentation, here is how they recommend you set up your stylesheet:

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">
```

If that doesn't work, or I misinterpreted your question, feel free to clarify what the problem is :D

Comment: :D what's wrong couldn't understand bro I feel like tried

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding what you're saying. If English isn't your first language feel free to speak whatever language you want and i'll just put it into google translate :)